# Массив байт в изображение

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Мне нужно создать двумерный массив и конвертировать его в изображение, заполнив при этом каким-то любым символом. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Двумерный массив создавать умеете? А вообще - непонятно объяснили, что именно хотите сделать.

Comment: Да, умею. Задачку мне разъяснили.
Получается, что суть такова, что на элементе Canvas нужно расположить двумерный массив, а именно если array[i, j] == 0, то пиксель на канвасе не подсвечивать, если array[i, j] == 1, то подсветить каким-то любым цветом. 

Суть всей задачки: есть монохромный пиксельный дисплей и по СОМ порту мне отправляется этот массив, а именно изображение этого дисплея.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример, отрисовывающий прямоугольники согласно данным из массива.

Аналогично можно и работать с пикселами, только размер массива должен быть побольше, чтобы что-то увидеть.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 0, 1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 1 }};
            Graphics dc = this.CreateGraphics();
            Brush[] brushes = {new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 
                               new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White) };
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    dc.FillRectangle(brushes[array2D[i, j]], j * 20, i * 20, 20, 20);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вот только на какой элемент повесить код? Я в шарпах и студии не очень. Всегда на Qt Creator работал, сильно не пинайте :)

Comment: Это на кнопку, но это только пример, такой путь отрисовки неверный. Нужно сформировать картинку и отрисовывать её в OnPaint.

Comment: Я понял, что по кнопке, но изображение куда выводится?

Comment: В данном случае на форму (this), можно использовать PictureBox. Однако при перерисовке (свернуть-развернуть) всё сотрётся, поэтому и стоит либо создать битмап, либо при каждом OnPaint рисовать квадраты заново (может быть разумно, если массив постоянно меняется)

Comment: Спасибо большое. А изображение действительно будет меняться динамически так как я этот массив считываю с СОМ порта

Comment: Для начала возьмите PictureBox, в его OnPaint вызывайте функцию отрисовки массива, в по приходу данных обновляйте `PictureBox.Refresh`